# Docker Container Command cannot locate shell script

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian

MAINTAINER Andrew Ford<andrew.ford@gg.com>
RUN apt-get update
COPY entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

and here is my entrypoint.sh (same directory as Dockerfile)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello
```

then I ran:

```
docker build --no-cache=true -t test/dockerfile-sayhello .
```

and when I ran:

```
docker run test/dockerfile-sayhello
```

it returns:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Container command '/entrypoint.sh' not found or does not exist..
```

I have tried googling around to try to see if I have made any obvious mistake, but so far I haven't been able to identify it. Maybe some of you can help

Edit: also ran chmod +x entrypoint.sh to give permission

Comment: What does `docker run test/dockerfile-sayhello ls -l /entrypoint` output? Does your script file have unix line endings?

Comment: It returns the same thing, yes it does have unix line endings

Comment: Try `./entrypoint.sh` instead.

Comment: Also tried ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"], but returns same error

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with the following Dockerfile (adding the `chmod`)

```
FROM debian

MAINTAINER Andrew Ford<andrew.ford@gg.com>
RUN apt-get update
COPY entrypoint.sh /

RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And it works as expected.

---

It is not like [issue 20789](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20789#issuecomment-196427880):

> I tried to transform a Dockerfile setup from phusion/baseimage to gliderslabs/alpine. Turns out that those shell scripts use `bash` -- of course! Simply change to `sh`, as `bash` is not present, resulting in the above error..

The latest [debian image](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-debian/blob/c2882c541f5bd5cfdd28a505a4e635d42c7fd946/jessie/Dockerfile) should include bash since its default `CMD` is `/bin/bash`.